# Add multiple cloud-sql-instances to beta-settings in Flexi

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying to add 4 separate sql's to the `beta_settings` subheading in my `app.yaml` file for Python3 Flexible App Engine. When I add the set of 4 together, separated by commas like so:

```
beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: X1, X2, X3, X4
```

I receive:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
```

How can I have multiple SQL-instances assigned to the `beta-settings`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I discovered that it's not possible to host multiple TCP connections on the same port. Hence, I needed to add a TCP port to each instance like so, with X representing `project-id:connection-name:db`

```
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: X1=tcp:3306,X2=tcp:3307,...Xn
```

Note there's **no spaces between instances** and **a unique tcp connection** per instance. Mistakes in the `app.yaml` file sometimes are described as simple `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.` - this can make for tedious and time-consuming debugging so save yourself the time and double-check syntax!

Good luck!

Comment: I could not get this to work. 

I used this setting: `cloud_sql_instances: project:region:db=tcp:5432,project:region:db-replica=tcp:5433`.

I can talk to the first instance in the list on `172.17.0.1:5432`, but I cannot connect to the second instance on `172.17.0.1:5433`.

Weirdly enough, the logs show that the first instance is listening on `0.0.0.0` while the second instance is listening on `127.0.0.1`. Not sure why the IPs are different even though I never configured this anywhere. Any idea how to connect to the second instance? There is no documentation for this :(